# Subversion + Tortoise commands to create a fork or branch

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a **Subversion** repository for source code. I need to create a branch based on the code as it was six years ago. I need to make modifications to this old code, and commit it back to the repository (as a branch). This code will never be merged into the main trunk.

What are the step-by-step **Tortoise** commands to create the branch or fork, and how do I commit the changes back to the repository?

---

More details:
Assume my main working copy is in `C:\ACME`. I need to keep this version going on my computer as it is the current production version.

I did a SVN Checkout to `F:\ACME_OLD`, going back to an older 2017 version. Then I made some changes to that version. I now want to create a branch and commit the changes in F:\ACME_OLD back to the repository. These changes will not be merged into the main branch, they will live a life of their own. What would the Tortoise commands be?

I cannot find an `SVN.EXE` file on my computer. I am hesitant to switch to calling SVN directly from the command line, because of misunderstandings or misconceptions about directory structure.

Do I right-click and do `TortoiseSVN ➔ Branch/tag` on `F:\ACME_OLD`, or on `C:\ACME` and then copy my changes from F: to C:?

I need to keep both versions active on my computer.

Sorry but I am apprehensive about experimenting or going the wrong way on my production system.

Answer (score 2):

In Subversion, branches and tags are created using the *copy* subcommand. Conceptually, you copy one version of your software to a branch as you would copy files on your file system.

I'll describe the CLI commands first as they are concise and clear. The CLI is installed alongside TortoiseSVN but not necessarily added to `PATH`. Assuming you're in a working copy and your repo has the default trunk/branches/tags layout, the operation would look like this:

```
svn copy -r {2017-10-11} ^/trunk ^/branches/archeology -m"Create branch from trunk of six years ago"
# Switch to the newly created branch
svn switch ^/branches/archeology
# Make your changes as usual ...
# Commit your changes back into the branch
svn commit -m"Wow, that was a lot of work"
```

Note that the example above used the [revision dates](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.tour.revs.dates) feature. The `{2017-10-11}` will resolve to whatever was the last revision October 11th 2017 shortly after midnight.

If you know the revision you want to start from, you can use it as well.

Using TortoiseSVN's GUI, the process is the same, only you use the GUI as described in the [doc on creating branches](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.tour.revs.dates).

That's *TortoiseSVN* -> *Branch/Tag ...*. In the dialog, enter a path for your new branch and a log message. Select *Specific revision in the repository* and either enter the revision number or use the *Show log* button to browse to the  starting point for your branch. (Unfortunately, I do not know whether TortoiseSVN accepts revision dates as well and cannot test right now but it's worth a try.)
Create the branch with the *Ok* button.

Don't forget to switch to your working copy to your newly created branch using *TortoiseSVN* -> *Switch ...*.

After making your changes, *Commit* them.

Subversion is actually very well documented so checking the docs is always worth a try.

---

*The part below addresses the edit of the question.*

Concerning `svn.exe`: it could be you have to check that option during TortoiseSVN's installation. I routinely do that. I'm more of a shell person. You don't need the CLI, if you want to have it, consider re-installing.

I can relate to your concerns about things going wrong on your production system. Nobody wants that to happen. One of Subversion's strong points is that it's very hard to actually break anything as a user. Local changes are preserved, unwanted changes can be *reverse-merged* and even deleted files and branches can still be accessed at the revision when they existed.

If you want to have an extra layer of security, make local copies of your working copies. If you want to be super-secure, backup your repo using `svnadmin dump` (you should regularly back up anyway). Although my educated guess is that it's easier to break your repo through abuse of `svnadmin` than by botching branch creation.

Getting back to the problem at hand. Branch creation is a *repository operation*. You don't need to run it from a working copy at all. In my example above, the caret `^` is conveniently replaced with the repository URL by Subversion (e.g. `https://svn.example.com/ACME`). You actually use the [URL -> URL form of copy](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.copy.html) to create a branch.

As we're going to continue there, go to `F:\ACME_OLD` to create the branch. Follow the instructions by TortoiseSVN linked above to create a branch. Just make sure you set the *Specific revision in the repository* to your 2017 revision.

So you would copy from e.g. `https://svn.example.com/ACME/trunk` (or whatever your "mainline" branch is called) to a new branch `https://svn.example.com/ACME/branches/OLD`. There are really just two things you need to pay attention to:

- you put in the proper 2017 revision as start revision
- your new branch is in parallel to your `trunk` and not below it

After that's done, *Switch* your `F:\ACME_OLD` to your newly created `https://svn.example.com/ACME/branches/OLD`. When you *Update*, you should not see a lot of changes as your working copy should already be in that state. Your local changes should also be preserved.

After checking that everything did work out, you can *SVN Commit...* your changes in `F:\ACME_OLD` and they should be visible only on the branch and not (after *SVN Update*) in `C:\ACME`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. See additional info in post.

Comment: @Pierre updated my answer to address your edit. Your edit did a lot to improve your question.

Comment: Thank you for your generous and detailed answer. Sorry to be obtuse, but my mainline is at "http://MyServer.MyDomain.com/svn/ACME". There is no explicit "trunk". You emphasize that the branch should be parallel to the trunk and not subordinate. But if I do that (vg. "http://MyServer.MyDomain.com/svn/ACME_OLD"), this would be a separate project. I'm not sure this is what I want to do?

Comment: I wrote it like that because I had a feeling that might be the case. You're not the first person to add a trunk, see [SVN creating trunk directory on existing repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345683/svn-creating-trunk-directory-on-existing-repository). Essentially, you create a `trunk` directory and *move* your files there.

Comment: That sounds fraught with peril. I'll have to rehearse the process by staging a test server and going through all the steps. What would the repository look like to the clients after moving? I think the more risk-free solution is to simply create a new project with the forked code. Thank you again for your expert help.

Comment: @Pierre current users would have to *switch* their working copies from `^/ACME` to `^/ACME/trunk`. I wouldn't see the entire operation as a risk but it's up to you. I can think of two alternatives: 1) you could  *export* your 2017 code to another repo's working copy or 2) duplicate your ACME repo using `svnadmin` commands and then *reverse-merge* everything after 2017. The latter is more work but would preserve history.

Comment: My colleagues in a former job suddenly decided to stop creating the trunk/branches/tags structure in new repositories for some reason only known to them, and I had to add it mid-project. It's annoying but not too risky (only a little). In particular, you need to be very careful to use the SVN Move command, as opposed to merely moving files around in Windows explorer. Otherwise, you'll lose a good bunch of history. So, yes, test it first with a copy (dump + load) of your repo :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not fully sure of what your doubts are, but I suspect there might be some confusion around the overall Subversion model. Key concepts:

- Subversion is a **centralised** version control system (the opposite of distributed systems like Git). You commit changes from working copy to repository and you update working copies to grab repository changes.  You never transmit information directly between two working copies. There is not even a command or tool to do it.
- Subversion does not actually implement branches or tags. They are nothing but a naming **convention**, base on two features:

  - Cheap copies. Copying a directory in Subversion does not cause all the files to be duplicated and storage to double. Only a reference is stored.
  - Working copies can point to any specific subdirectory, you don't have to check out the entire repository.

  This allows to have a directory structure above your project's root that can be used to create additional directories with copies of your project root that will be conventionally considered branches or tags.

The most widespread and recommended convention is to have this structure:

```
__ trunk
\_ branches
   \_ feature-a
   \_ feature-b
   \_ ...
\_ tags
   \_ 1.0.0
   \_ 1.1.0
   \_ 2.0.0-alpha1
   \_ ...
```

`trunk` would be the equivalent of `master` / `main` branch used by Git.

TortoiseSVN understands this convention and will offer some additional features (for example, it'll warn you if you attempt to write on a tag).